# getting error on conditional rendering with stateless component

Tags: reactjs

When I check the length of item, and trying to add in to template, getting error. any one help me to fix this issue?

here is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import "./style-posts.css";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { setTitle, titleHandler } from "../actions/postActions";

const ShowPosts = props => {
  if (props.posts.length) {
    const postItems = props.posts.map(post => {
      <div key={post.id}>
        <h3>{post.title}</h3>
        <p>{post.body}</p>
      </div>;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {props.posts.length ? postItems : null} //postItems is not defined
      <button onClick={props.showPosts}>Show Posts On Click </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(
  setTitle,
  titleHandler
)(ShowPosts);
```

getting error as `postItems is not defined` - what is wrong with me code? any one figure out?

Answer (score 1):

Its because `postItems` is a const and you defined `postItems` variable inside if block, so it will be available in that block only. (let and const have block scope and var has function level scope).

Write it like this:

```
let postItems = null;

if (props.posts.length) {
    postItems = props.posts.map(post => (
        <div key={post.id}>
            <h3>{post.title}</h3>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
        </div>;
    ));
}
```

Or use `var` instead of `const`.

```
if (props.posts.length) {
    var postItems = props.posts.map(post => (
        <div key={post.id}>
            <h3>{post.title}</h3>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
        </div>;
    ));
}
```

I will suggest to check this answer for difference between let, var and const:

[What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav)

Comment: will it work with `const` I think `let` should be there

Comment: @Revansiddh my mistake, updated the answer thanks :)

Comment: because you are not returning anything from map callback method. check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**It can be const**:

```
const postItems = !props.posts.length ? []
  : props.posts.map(post => (
    <div key={post.id}>
      <h3>{post.title}</h3>
      <p>{post.body}</p>
    </div>;
  ));
```

No rendered data because no `mapStateToProps`, no proper `mapDispatchToProps`, simply bad redux `connect` usage.